# SQL: how to select max value from one table and other data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to select `naziv` and `slika` from the first table (`predmet` table), and `iznos_ponude` from the second table (`ponuda` table).

It's an auction system. The first table represents the objects on auction (BMW, Mercedes etc.), the second table represents the id (`predmet_id` is the foreign key) of the object and the bid for that object.

I need to display EVERY object with the HIGHEST bid for it.

Example: `BMW - IMAGE URL - 17000`

This will help you understand better:

```
naziv = name
slika = image
iznos_ponude = bid
```

[image: "predmet" table]

[image: "ponuda" table]

Comment: What is your DBMS? SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: We need question and sample data and expected output all in the text format same as you look like in the SQL server table not in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this in SQL Server using `row_number()` like following.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT t1.naziv, 
               t1.slika, 
               T2.iznos_ponude, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER( 
                   partition BY T2.predmet_id 
                   ORDER BY iznos_ponude DESC) rn 
        FROM   predmet T1 
               INNER JOIN ponuda T2 
                       ON T1.predmet_id = T2.predmet_id)t 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Same thing can also be achieved using subquery like following.

```
SELECT t1.naziv, 
       t1.slika, 
       (SELECT Max(iznos_ponude) 
        FROM   ponuda 
        WHERE  predmet_id = T1.predmet_id) iznos_ponude 
FROM   predmet T1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include objects with no bids, use `left join` and `group by`:

```
select p.naziv, p.slika, max(po.iznos_ponude)
from predmet p left join
     ponude po
     on po.predmet_id = p.predmet_id
group by p.naziv, p.slika;
```